# Cómo mostrar menú con permisos por perfil en CodeIgniter3?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, codeigniter-3

Estoy intentando mostrar un menu en codeigniter 3 con postgresql, el cual cambia sus resultados según los permisos del perfil.

Resulta que el código me funciona a la perfección en sqlserver, pero al intentarlo con postgres me arroja este error errores, a le cambia las comillas, he intentado varias cosas pero no logro solucionarlo

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «[» LINE 6: ORDER BY case when CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(SUBSTRING([MENU_ORDE... ^

Filename: postgre/postgre_driver.php

Line Number: 242
Se produjo un error en la base de datos

 Error Number:

ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «[» LINE 6: ORDER BY case when CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(SUBSTRING([MENU_ORDE... ^

SELECT "MENU_ORDEN" FROM "MENU" JOIN "permisos" ON "menu"."MENU_ID" = "permisos"."MENU_ID" WHERE "permisos"."PERFIL_ID" = '2' AND "MENU"."MENU_ESTADO" = 1 ORDER BY case when CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(SUBSTRING([MENU_ORDEN], 0, CHARINDEX('.', [MENU_ORDEN])), '.', '')) = 0 then [MENU_ORDEN] else CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(SUBSTRING([MENU_ORDEN], 0, CHARINDEX('.', [MENU_ORDEN])), '.', '')) end, CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(SUBSTRING([MENU_ORDEN], 3, CHARINDEX('.', "MENU_ORDEN", 1)), '.', '')), CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(SUBSTRING([MENU_ORDEN], 4, CHARINDEX('.', "MENU_ORDEN", 2)), '.', ''))

Filename: models/Model_menu.php

Line Number: 29
```

codigo modelo

```
public function menu($perfil_id)
{
    $this->db->select("MENU_ORDEN", "MENU_NOMBRE", "MENU_link", false);
    $this->db->from("MENU");
    if ($this->session->userdata("perfil_id") != '2');
    {
        $this->db->join("permisos", "menu.MENU_ID = permisos.MENU_ID");
        $this->db->where('permisos.PERFIL_ID',$perfil_id );
    }
    $this->db->where("MENU.MENU_ESTADO",1 );
    $this->db->order_by("
            case when CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(SUBSTRING([MENU_ORDEN], 0, CHARINDEX('.', [MENU_ORDEN])),'.','')) = 0 
                then [MENU_ORDEN] else CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(SUBSTRING([MENU_ORDEN], 0, CHARINDEX('.', [MENU_ORDEN])),'.','')) end, 
            CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(SUBSTRING([MENU_ORDEN], 3, CHARINDEX('.', MENU_ORDEN, 1)),'.','')), 
            CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(SUBSTRING([MENU_ORDEN], 4, CHARINDEX('.', MENU_ORDEN, 2)),'.',''))");
    $menu = $this->db->get()->result_array(); //LINEA 29

    if(count($menu) > 0){
        $menu = json_encode($menu);
        $retorno = array(
            "cod"    => '0',
            "des"    => 'Exito',
            "menu" => $menu
        );
    }else{
        $retorno = array(
            "cod"    => '1',
            "des"    => 'Error',
            "menu"   => array()
        );
    }

    return $retorno;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asegúrate de que la consulta generada por Codeigniter tenga la forma siguiente:

```
SELECT    
   "MENU_ORDEN" 
FROM "MENU" 
    JOIN "PERMISOS" 
    ON "MENU"."MENU_ID" = "PERMISOS"."MENU_ID" 
WHERE 
    "PERMISOS"."PERFIL_ID" = '3' 
    AND "MENU"."MENU_ESTADO" = 1 
ORDER BY 
    "MENU_ORDEN"
```